# How to replace an object in MSMutableArray with another object

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

OK.  I've spent a ridiculous amount of time on this.  I've looked all around on the internet to the point of feeling pretty stupid.  I have program which is an array of x, 2, "+".  So I make a copy of program and try to replace x with its value (5) from variableValues.

Can anyone tell me how in the world to do this?

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVaraiableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues {

    NSMutableArray *program2 = program;
    for (NSString *obj in program) {
        NSNumber *number = [variableValues objectForKey:obj];
        if (number) {
            int index = [program indexOfObject:obj];
            NSLog(@"index = %i", index);
            [program2 replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:number];
        }
    }
    return [self runProgram:program2];
}
```

Comment: `program2 = program` doesn't make a copy, much less a mutable one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `program2` isn't a copy of `program`, it is a reference to the same memory address. Try doing `NSMutableArray *program2 = [program mutableCopy];` instead.

Comment: This probably won't work since `program` is of type `id`.  :-P

Comment: Ok, maybe, but not probably. Furthermore, if `program` isn't a `NSArray`, this line probably won't work too `int index = [program indexOfObject:obj];`.

Comment: Yeah, the problem though, is that the compiler won't recognize the `id` as accepting the message `mutableCopy`.  It needs to be cast to an `NSArray`...

Comment: Or better yet, just change the signature of the method so that it requires an array.  That way we always know what we are getting.  :)

Comment: Thank you, guys.  I wish I could add points.  You both are great!!